# edit gtkcellrenderertext

Tags: c, treeview, gtk3, renderer

I am writing a gtk3(in C) code, that uses treeview.

```
store = gtk_list_store_new (NUM_COLS, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING,
                                                G_TYPE_STRING,
                                                G_TYPE_STRING,
                                                G_TYPE_STRING);

  tree = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model (GTK_TREE_MODEL (store));
  cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  col_pub=gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes (
                                               "Title", cell,
                                               "text", COL_BIB_PUB,
                                               NULL);
gtk_tree_view_column_set_sort_column_id( col_pub, ID_PUB);
gtk_tree_view_append_column (GTK_TREE_VIEW (tree), col_pub);
```

The problem is I want each cell of the treeview to be editable, so I need something like:

```
g_object_set(cell, "editable", TRUE, NULL);
```

but I have no idea of how to connect the edited flag to file/buffer.
It will be very helpful if someone kindly show the way...a very short example may be.

Comment: You need to explain better what you want to achieve. In the mean time, I will suggest you to look into gtk3-demo application (which is shipped with Gtk+). There is a GtkListStore example with editable cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect the Gtk.CellRendererText to a signal. All your TreeViewColumn that uses this renderer will connect to the signal.

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (cell), "edited", G_CALLBACK (cb), NULL)

    void cb (GtkCellRendererText *rend, char*path, char*newtext, gpointer data)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the newtext
       ........          

    // Since this signal emitted after cell being edited,
    // you can use a global variable (a bool maybe) to indicate.
    // gboolean switcher = 0   
    switcher = 1
}
```

If that's what you want since your question is not clear